# Need help installing pip

Tags: apt, python, pip

I have issues with my current pip installation.
running the command pip -v shows that it is installed for python 3.10 instead of python2:

```
└─# pip -V
pip 22.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

When I try to manually install pip for python 2 I get the below error:

```
└─# sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip-whl : Breaks: python-pip-whl (< 21.3.1+dfsg-2~) but 18.1-5 is to be installed
 python3-setuptools-whl : Breaks: python-pip-whl (< 21.3.1+dfsg-2~) but 18.1-5 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I am trying to install pip for python2 and pip3 for python 3 (Each python version with its own pip, if that makes sense!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1433796/edit) to include the complete output of  `apt-cache policy python3-pip-whl`

Comment: "instead of python2" python2 does not exist anymore. If you have software depending on p2 you should update it to python3. Fixes a lot of other issues ;-)